# Creating a Batch to parse a text file, find a folder and copy it and its tree

Tags: batch-file

I am having a hard time trying to make it works. 
Here is my batch file, just for the test I have put an internal set.
I want to parse a text file with in it a list of folder name, find the folder and copy only the folder and its content and its tree.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set str=SMX47
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-d /ad') do if "%%~na" == "%str%" copy "%%a" "C:\Test\testcopy"
```

It finds a folder named `SMX47` and copy its content only in the folder `testcopy`.
I would like to get :

`\GP\GV\SMX47\` (so the tree) and the content of the folder `SMX47`.

Thanks for your help guys.
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  Remove pause, @echo on, and @echo off (at end) when you have it all working.

```
@echo off
set str=SMX47
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-d /ad') do (
   if "%%~na" == "%str%" (
      call :CopyFolderStructure "%%a"
      )
   )
pause
goto :eof

:CopyFolderStructure
set FolderStructure=%~1
call set FolderStructure=%%FolderStructure:%cd%=%%
@echo on
xcopy /i /y "%~1\*.*" "C:\Test\testcopy%FolderStructure%\"
@echo off
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks RGuggisberg for your help, well done it works but when trying it with a mapped drive, I am having the "invalid path error" because it is trying to copy files in 
C:\Temp\Z:\data\.....

Comment: @echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (list_pn.txt) do (   
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-d /ad "Z:\data"') do (
 if "%%~na" == "%%b" (
  call :CopyFolderStructure "%%a"
  )
 )
 )
goto :eof

:CopyFolderStructure
set FolderStructure=%~1
call set FolderStructure=%%FolderStructure:%cd%=%%
xcopy /I /Y /Q "%~1\*.*" "C:\Temp%FolderStructure%\"
goto :eof